# How can I stop html5 canvas from making this additional rectangles with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am doing a canvas where I show a projectile motion. I have this problem where my canvas is drawing additional rectangles in a for loop. If i take off the for loop and draw a single rectangle, the same rectangle is drawn without a fill. My problem gets kind of solved with end path (there is a pic and the code at the bottom for the endPath() part), but I lose my basketball image/drawing.

[image: Canvas]

In my code I use two context.beginPath. This is my code:

```
function objetos2(){
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    if(x>900 && tiempo>11)
    {
        context.moveTo(canvas.width, y);
    }
    else
    {
        context.moveTo(x, y);
    }

if(x>900 && tiempo>11)
{
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, y-vy);
    context.lineTo(-5+canvas.width, y-vy-10);
    context.lineTo(5+canvas.width, y-vy-10);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, y-vy);
}
else
{
    context.beginPath();
    for(i=0;i<canvas.width-100;i+=200)
    {
        context.fillStyle = "brown";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "brown"; 
        context.rect(-x+i+210, 450,  10, 50);
    }
    context.beginPath();
    for(i=0;i<canvas.width-399;i+=200)
    {
        context.fillStyle = "grey";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "grey"; 
        context.rect(-x+i+220, 450,  190, 5);
        context.rect(-x+i+220, 470,  190, 5);
    }
}
context.stroke();
}
```

This is where my functions get called:

```
function dibupun(vx,vy){
    context.clearRect(0,0,900,500);
    var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    trazaraltura(vy);
    velocidadx(vx, vy);
    velocidady(vy);
    context.save();
    context.shadowOffsetY = 25;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 20;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowBlur = 0.5;
    context.shadowColor = 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1)';
    objetos2();
    context.restore();

    context.beginPath();

    flechay(vy);
    flechax(vx, vy);

    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = "blue"; 
    context.stroke();

    if(x>900 && tiempo>11)
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, canvas.width-100-14, y-14, 30, 30);
    }
    else
    {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, x-14, y-14, 30, 30);
    }
};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.dpcdsb.org/NR/rdonlyres/132B2859-0F1F-42F6-BE18-A151ABF439BE/105710/basketball.png';
sombras();
}
```

Something I want to mention is that when I use those two context.beginPath() and then use an endPath() it draws normally but I lose my basketball image/drawing inside the canvas.

```
context.beginPath();
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-100;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "brown";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "brown"; 
            context.rect(-x+i+210, 450,  10, 50);
        }
        context.beginPath();
        for(i=0;i<canvas.width-380;i+=200)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "grey";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeStyle = "grey"; 
            context.rect(-x+i+220, 450,  190, 5);
            context.rect(-x+i+220, 470,  190, 5);
        }
        context.endpath();
```

[image: Basketball got lost with endPath()]

Comment: Didn't read the full question but for the endPath part, it's not a context2d method, which will throw an exception and stop the execution of further code.

Comment: @Kaiido I solved it myself. Never got an exception, but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, I just made it invisible. Here is the code:

```
    for(i=0;i<canvas.width-199;i+=200)
    {
        context.fillStyle = "brown";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "brown"; 
        context.rect(-x+i+210, 450,  10, 50);
        if(i>canvas.width-200)
        {
            context.globalAlpha=0;
            context.rect(-x+i+210, 450,  10, 50);
        }
    }
    context.beginPath();
    for(i=0;i<canvas.width-399;i+=200)
    {
        context.fillStyle = "grey";
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = "grey"; 
        context.rect(-x+i+220, 450,  190, 5);
        context.rect(-x+i+220, 470,  190, 5);
        if(i>=canvas.width-400)
        {
            context.globalAlpha=0;
            context.fillRect(-x+i+220, 450,  190, 5);
            context.fillRect(-x+i+220, 470,  190, 5);
        }
```